characterization of Schur functions
In Mellit2016, page 6, beginning of section 4, Mellit says that the Schur functions are uniquely determined upto a scalar factor by the properties that

$s_\lambda$ is a linear combination of $m_\mu$ with $\mu \leq \lambda$,
$\omega(s_\lambda)$ is a linear combination of $m_\mu$ with $\mu \leq \lambda'$.

It is easy to see that Schur functions $s_\lambda$ indeed satisfies the above two properties. But I am unable to prove that these properties uniquely determine Schur functions.
Please help with proving this characterization of Schur functions.

In the original paper of MacDonald ("A New Class of Symmetric Functions), he provides a slightly different characterisation of Schur functions: namely that they are the unique collection such that

$s_\lambda = m_\lambda + \sum_{\mu < \lambda} K_{\lambda\mu} m_\mu$ for some coefficients $K_{\lambda\mu}$ — that is, $s_\lambda \in M_{\le\lambda}$, and
$(s_\lambda,s_\mu) = 0$ unless $\lambda=\mu$.

Here $(-,-)$ is the Hall pairing, which makes $h_\lambda$ and $m_\lambda$ dual bases (I am using Mellit's notation).
(The following is not obvious, see edit.) These assumptions imply that $s_\lambda$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the ring of symmetric functions, which is unique up to order as the only orthogonal matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ are permutations. EDIT: a better way to see that this characterises the Schur functions is as the result of the Gram-Schmit procedure applied to the basis of monomial symmetric functions, with respect to (a linear order extending) the dominance order. (Further edit: there is discussion to this effect in MacDonald's paper, see remark 1 on p. 139.)
Up to a scale factor, assumption (1) is the same as Mellit's. To get assumption (2), we will use the following fact (see Chapter I, 2.3 of MacDonald's book),
$$ e_{\lambda'} = m_{\lambda} + \sum_{\mu<\lambda}a_{\lambda\mu}m_\mu. $$
This implies in particular:
$$ M_{\le\lambda} = \text{Span}\{e_{\mu'} \;:\; \mu \le \lambda\} = \text{Span}\{e_{\mu} \;:\; \mu \ge \lambda'\}, $$
noting that $\mu \le \lambda$ iff $\mu' \ge \lambda'$.
Then we can calculate using Mellit's assumptions:
$$ (s_\lambda,s_\mu) = (s_\lambda,\omega^2\{s_{\mu}\}) = \left(\sum_{\rho\le\lambda} K_{\lambda\rho} m_\rho,\; \omega\left\{\sum_{\sigma\ge\mu} \tilde K_{\mu\sigma} e_\sigma\right\} \right) = \sum_{\mu\le\rho\le\lambda}K_{\lambda\rho}\tilde K_{\mu\rho}.$$
In particular, $(s_\lambda,s_\mu) = 0$ unless $\mu\le\lambda$. But, since the Hall pairing is symmetric, we can exchange the roles of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ (or just apply $\omega^2$ to the first argument), so this implies MacDonald's assumption (2).

Excellent. Thank you.
